# Time of last insert / update / delete in my database in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I need a function that returns last time of insert / update / delete in my database. I use Symfony 2 and Doctrine 2.

I have tried this raw query, but UPDATE_TIME is always NULL:

```
$connection = $this->getDoctrine()->getConnection();
$database = $connection->getDatabase();

$result = $connection->fetchAll('
    SELECT MAX(UPDATE_TIME)
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "' . $database . '"
');
```

How can I get this last time in Symfony or Doctrine? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I bet you're using `InnoDB`, and `InnoDB` [doesn't support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-table-status.html) `UPDATE_TIME`.

Your best bet is to create an event and populate/update a table each time you're inserting/updating a row.

Comment: Thanks. yes I'am using InnoDB. maybe you know how can I add this trigger in the best way in Symfony and Doctrine?

Comment: You can either use a native mysql [`TRIGGER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) or use [Doctrine's `EventManager`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.1/reference/events.html).